# Spring mvc Ajax search Form with Thymeleaf

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, spring-data, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add a search form in the navbar on every page in my spring mvc web app, just like the one here on stackoverflow, and I'm having issues.  Right now I have a working search functions on a couple of my pages, using the typical mvc forms.  I take the inputted string and store a variable called "searchString" in an object I created called "searchForm.java".  Then I try to query that inputted string in the database using spring data's findbycontaing method, and then put that result on the model, and then represent that on the view, using thymeleaf.  However I think that the navbar should be done using ajax, since it's on every page and pages with other forms.

So I think I'm sending the string that was submitted to the search form in the navbar to the controller where I queried it in the repository to bring back search results, then I tried to put the search results on the model, but I get nothing, all it does is redirect me to the search page.  I may not be making very much sense, but I'll show my code, and if anyone could let me know if I'm going about my problem in the right way or not, and if you guys see any errors in my code.  Thanks in advance.

So here's my ajax and jquery to submit the form.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchButton").on("click", function(ev) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "navSearch",
            type : "post",
            data : {
                "newSearch" : $("#newSearch").val()
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log("There was an error");
            }

        });
    });
  });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

There may be an issue here, because in the console in the chrome developer tools, before it redirects, a message pops up very quickly that says `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`, and it's coming from `jquery.min.js:5` so that could be my issue, but I have no idea how to go about fixing this, and I've searched for answers so far with no luck.

Here's my html form, I think this shouldn't be a problem, but who knows, so I'll put it up anyways. And I'm using thymeleaf for this view.

```
<form action = "setSearch" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="newSearch"></input>
            <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="searchButton">Search</button>
        </form>
```

Here's my searchForm.java class, where I temporarily store the string to be queried in the database.

```
public class SearchForm {

private String searchString;

public String getSearchString()
{
    return searchString;
}

public void setSearchString(String searchString)
{
    this.searchString = searchString;
}
}
```

And Here's my controller, where I'm trying to handle the ajax submission and return it as search results on the setSearch.html page.  What I'm thinking here is that the string "newSearch" from the form could be matched using the Spring Data query methods, and then be able to return it and add it to the model, but it's not working,  it's just redirecting me to the /searchSet page with no data, because that's where the form action goes and that's what I tell it to return.  So honestly I'm no sure if any data is even getting to this point.

```
@RequestMapping(value="setSearch/navSearch", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String navSearch (@RequestParam String newSearch, ModelMap model)
{   
    List<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSetByQuestion = (List<QuestionAnswerSet>) questionAnswerSetRepo.findByQuestionContaining(newSearch);
    model.put("searchResult", questionAnswerSetByQuestion);

    return "setSearch";
}
```

And here's an example of a working search method that I have in my controller that I use on a regular form, with no ajax, on the /searchSet page.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/setSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchGet(ModelMap model) {

    SearchForm searchForm = new SearchForm();
    model.put("searchForm", searchForm);

    return "setSearch";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/setSearch", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchPost(@ModelAttribute SearchForm searchForm, ModelMap model) {

    List<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSetByQuestion = (List<QuestionAnswerSet>) questionAnswerSetRepo.findByQuestionContaining(searchForm.getSearchString());
    model.put("searchResult", questionAnswerSetByQuestion);

    return "setSearch";
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed my code in the form from `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="searchButton">Search</button>` to `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="searchButton">Search</button>` and now I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` from earlier and nothing happens with the page.

**UPDATE**

I can now submit the ajax form without a problem, I was missing meta tags in the header, so the csrf wasn't submitting correctly, so now I get this error in the chrome developer tools console `XHR Loaded (navSearch - 405 Method Not Allowed - 7.265999971423298ms - 634B)`

**UPDATE**

Now everything works on the Ajax side, I needed to adjust my url to match the url I had in the request mapping on the controller and it runs through all the code fine.  However the overall search function still doesn't work, here's my updated controller.

I know my issue here is that I'm returning a string and not an object, but I'm not sure how to return the object and then redirect the url to the /setSearch page.  It's running through the code and returning a string "setSearch" in the console, because I told it to at the end of the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/setSearch/search", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String search (@RequestParam String newSearch, ModelMap model)
{   
    List<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSetByQuestion = (List<QuestionAnswerSet>) questionAnswerSetRepo.findByQuestionContaining(newSearch);
    model.put("searchResult", questionAnswerSetByQuestion);

    return "setSearch";
}
```

Here's my working ajax

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/

    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchButton").on("click", function(ev) {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/setSearch/search",
            type : "post",
            data : {
                "newSearch" : $("#newSearch").val()
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log("There was an error");
            }

        });
    });
  });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Few things, search should be a GET not a POST request (stick with Restfull principles). Next click on the error in console itself and have a look at where its coming from. Is it coming from javascript or your server code? Then copy the faulty code section and put it in the question.

Comment: The error is coming from `jquery.min.js:5`

Comment: Is the request posted? I don't see anything wrong in the code that you posted. Probably caused by some other code.

Comment: this is very strange, but now it says it's on line 9026, and when I click on that it has something to do with this section `setRequestHeader: function( name, value ) {
     var lname = name.toLowerCase();
     if ( !state ) {
      name = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] || name;
      requestHeaders[ name ] = value;
     }`

Comment: I see, so the problem is here `xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);`. Probably no meta with name `_csrf` and `csrf_header` are defined?

Comment: That's weird, because I use an ajax form with the same `xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);` on another form and it works just fine

Comment: Check the rendered HTML. Probably the meta tag is not present on the page where the search fragment is located.

Comment: thanks, you were right, but now I have issues with my backend code, so I'll go work on that

Comment: Here's my new problem `XHR Loaded (navSearch - 405 Method Not Allowed - 7.265999971423298ms - 634B)`, I'm not sure what that means.  Also I'll update the question.

Comment: Replace `url : "navSearch"` with `url : "setSearch/navSearch"`.

Comment: Probably you have another request mapping to `/navSearch` and the method set is `GET` instead of `POST`?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, it's returning the `"setSearch";` that I tell it to in the controller, the ajax is working fine, I just need to figure out the controller, and how to redirect the page to the "/setSearch" with the information that was submitted in the form.  I'll update the question to show you exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Bnrdo I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

> but it's not working, it's just redirecting me to the /searchSet page
>   with no data, because that's where the form action goes and that's
>   what I tell it to return

You are right, it is because you are submitting the form and in the action you specify it to submit to `setSearch`, that is why the page is getting redirected to the same page. Just replace `button type="submit"` with `button type="button"` so that the form will not be submitted when `searchButton` is clicked.

Comment: Ok, I changed that and now it's no longer redirecting, but I get the error `uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` in the console still.